# RVO on different compilers when using containers

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, rvo

I have the following code on c++17

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T*> getPointerVector(std::vector<T> base) {
  auto out = std::vector<T*>();
  for (auto& t : base) {
      out.push_back(&t);
  }
  return out;
}
```

As far as i understand RVO should kick in and prevent any copying of the returned vector. However, when i use GCC it all works fine, using msvc it does not and the vector is actually copied. Any explanations? Thanks!

Edit:
When I debugged I made sure the reference in memory is the same for the vector inside the function and on the calling side. That is true for gcc 8.3 on debian testing and not true for msvc on visual studio 19.4

Comment: How did you deduce it's copied? And are you sure it isn't being moved instead?

Comment: you do realize you're taking the vector parameter by value and essentially returning an array of dangling pointers... also, unrelated: that first line is better written `std::vector<T*> out;`. *might* be more conducive to optimization.

Comment: Be specific about which toolchains you're using. There have been many, many versions of both GCC and Visual Studio, on varying different platforms.

Comment: If you don't end up with dangling pointers it is by an accident of optimization. You do have undefined behavior if you don't pass your vector by reference into the function.

Comment: Otherwise your vector should at the very least be *moved* out of the function when it is returned (assuming C++11).

Comment: Covered both those things in the answers already @Galik :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your version of Visual Studio just doesn't do that.

Or…

> When I debugged I made sure the reference in memory is the same for the vector inside the function and on the calling side. That is true for gcc 8.3 on debian testing and not true for msvc on visual studio 19.4

If you're debugging, presumably you're making a debug build, for which optimisations are usually much less fierce. So it could simply be that you turned this off.

It will at least be *moving* the vector, so there's that.

By the way, every element of the vector you're returning is a dangling pointer. Did you mean to take `base` by reference? Also, an `out.reserve(base.size())` call wouldn't hurt.

Comment: **N**RVO is not mandated in C++17. And OP used (named) variable.